# Variable scope within list comprehension

Tags: python, list, variables, scope, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples which comprise of a string and another list;

```
[('string1', ['a1', 'b1']),
 ('string2', ['a2', 'b2']),
 ('string3', ['a3', 'b3'])]
```

I cannot figure out using list comprehension to arrive at something like;

```
[['string1a1', 'string1b1'],
 ['string2a2', 'string2b2'],
 ['string3a3', 'string3b3']]
```

I tried something like

```
results = [join(ministring, i) for i in (miniarray for (ministring, miniarray) in myarray)]
```

but i am confused at each variables scope within the expansion/expression(?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
lst = [('string1', ['a1', 'b1']),
 ('string2', ['a2', 'b2']),
 ('string3', ['a3', 'b3'])]

res = [[master + tail for tail in sublist] for master, sublist in lst]
```

which returns:

```
[['string1a1', 'string1b1'], ['string2a2', 'string2b2'], ['string3a3', 'string3b3']]
```

---

Note that with this approach the length of the sublist inside the tuple is not fixed. It can be arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
data = [('string1', ['a1', 'b1']),
 ('string2', ['a2', 'b2']),
 ('string3', ['a3', 'b3'])]

result = [[s + e1, s + e2] for s, [e1, e2] in data]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['string1a1', 'string1b1'], ['string2a2', 'string2b2'], ['string3a3', 'string3b3']]
```

Note that this assumes the inner list have only two elements.

Comment: OP only said "another list", though, not that this list will always have two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_list = list(map(lambda x: [x[0]+x[1][0], x[0]+x[1][1]],data))
```